# Calculation of euler phi function

Tags: algorithm, math, implementation

```
int phi (int n) {
    int result = n;
    for (int i=2; i*i<=n; ++i)
        if (n % i == 0) {
            while (n % i == 0)
                n /= i;
            result -= result / i;
        }
    if (n > 1)
        result -= result / n;
    return result;
}
```

I saw the above implementation of **Euler phi function** which is of the **O(sqrt n)**.I don't get the fact of using `i*i<=n` in the `for` loop and need of changing `n`.It is said that it can be done in a time much smaller **O (sqrt n)** How? [link (in Russian)](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/euler_function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i*i<=n` is same as `i<= sqrt(n)` from which your iteration lasts only to order of `sqrt(n)`.

Using the straight definition of [Euler totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) you are supposed to find the prime numbers that divides `n`.

Answer (score 2):

The function is a straight forward implementation of integer factorization by trial division, except that instead of reporting the factors as it finds them the function uses the factors to calculate phi. Calculation of phi can be done in time less than O(sqrt n) by using a better algorithm to find the factors; the best way to do that depends on the magnitude of *n*.

Comment: What is meant by better algorithm to find the factors?.Plz mention the name of the algorithm

Comment: The rho and p-1 algorithms, SQUFOF, continued fractions, elliptic curve algorithm, quadratic sieve, number field sieve, and many others that don't come to mind at the moment. Beware that some of these only work well in the hands of experts.

Comment: @DCoder Why not follow the link on the page you cited just after it says you can find phi "faster than O(sqrt(n))?" That link answers the question, which should not be a surprise because it also says "efficient algorithms for factoring." It describes things like Pollard rho factorization which beats trial division for 20+ digit numbers. I don't understand how you could read that page and not be willing to follow the links on it.

Answer (score 1):

If the biggest number (N say) that you will want the totient of is small enough that you can have a table of size N in memory, then you can do a lot better, per evaluation, at the cost of having to build a table before any evaluations.

One approach would be to build a table of primes first, and then instead of using trial division by every integer at most sqrt(n), use trial division by every prime at most sqrt(n).

You could improve on this by building, instead of a table of primes, a table that gives (for each integer 2..N) the smallest prime that divides the number. A simple modification of the usual [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) can be used to build such a table. Then to compute the totient of a number you use the table to find the smallest prime dividing the number (and accumulate that into you answer), then divide the number by the table entry, use the table to find the smallest prime that divides that, and so on.